# Greyout/disable a field with ng-model

Tags: html, angular

I have 3 radio buttons with ng-model - client.ssoApiClientAuth and ids - apiClientAuthMeth0, apiClientAuthMeth1, apiClientAuthMeth2

I have a password field with ng-model - client.newPassword and id - apiClientSecret.

I need to greyout/disable password field when apiClientAuthMeth1 is selected.

I am not familiar with these Angular techniques. Could anyone tell me the solution?

Comment: You talk about `ng-model`, but also talk about Angular, so are you working with AngularJS or Angular? Currently you have tagged angular in your question, so just check that you are using correct tags :)

Answer (score 2):

If you have the apiClientAuthMethN as property in your component you can disable fields like this:

```
<div [disabled]="apiClientAuthMeth1"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

To disable password property use `[disabled]="apiClientAuthMeth"`.
`apiClientAuthMeth` will be a boolean variable.

When `apiClientAuthMeth1` is selected call a function to typescript and set `apiClientAuthMeth` to true. This will disable your field and if another radiobutton is selected then make this variable false and it will enable your password field